# How to align arrays when enumerate

Tags: math-mode, align, environments, enumerate, arrays

[image]

Hi! I wanted to copy that image in my document, but i don't know how to align the arrays used in that code. Here what I did:

```
\begin{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}

    \item
    $$
\begin{array}{rl} 

 \mbox{minimizar} & z = 3x_1 + x_2 \\ 

 \mbox{sujeto a} & x_1 - x_2 \leq 1 \\

  & 3x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 12 \\

  & 2x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 3\\

  & -2x_1 + 3x_2 \geq 9\\

  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 \\

 \end{array}

$$

    \item
    $$

\begin{array}{rl} 

 \mbox{minimizar} & z = x_1 - 2x_2 \\ 

 \mbox{sujeto a} & x_1 - 2x_2 \geq 4 \\

  & x_1 + x_2 \leq 8 \\

  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 \\

 \end{array}

$$

    \item
    $$

\begin{array}{rl} 

 \mbox{maximizar} & z = x_1 + 2x_2 \\

  \mbox{sujeto a} & 2x_1 + x_2 \geq 12 \\

  & x_1 + x_2 \geq 5 \\

  & -x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 3 \\

  & 6x_1 - x_2 \geq 12 \\

  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 \\

 \end{array}

$$

    \item
        $$

\begin{array}{rl} 

 \mbox{minimizar} & z = -x_1 - x_2 \\ 

 \mbox{sujeto a} & x_1 - x_2 \geq 1 \\

  & x_1 - 2x_2 \geq 2 \\

  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 \\

 \end{array}

$$
```

But, as you can see, Latex don't adjust the items, and I don't know how to do that.
Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following code?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}

\item
    $$
\begin{array}{rl} 

 \mbox{minimizar} & z = 3x_1 + x_2 \\ 

 \mbox{sujeto a} & x_1 - x_2 \leq 1 \\

  & 3x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 12 \\

  & 2x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 3\\

  & -2x_1 + 3x_2 \geq 9\\

  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 \\

 \end{array}
$$

\item
$$
\begin{array}{rl} 

 \mbox{minimizar} & z = x_1 - 2x_2 \\ 

 \mbox{sujeto a} & x_1 - 2x_2 \geq 4 \\

  & x_1 + x_2 \leq 8 \\

  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 \\

 \end{array}
$$

\newpage
\item
$$
\begin{array}{rl} 

 \mbox{maximizar} & z = x_1 + 2x_2 \\

  \mbox{sujeto a} & 2x_1 + x_2 \geq 12 \\

  & x_1 + x_2 \geq 5 \\

  & -x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 3 \\

  & 6x_1 - x_2 \geq 12 \\

  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 \\

 \end{array}
$$

\item
$$
\begin{array}{rl} 

 \mbox{minimizar} & z = -x_1 - x_2 \\ 

 \mbox{sujeto a} & x_1 - x_2 \geq 1 \\

  & x_1 - 2x_2 \geq 2 \\

  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 \\

 \end{array}
$$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in this instance the original author wrapped the whole enumerate in `\begin{multicols}{2}`…`\end{multicols}` (which necessitates adding `\usepackage{multicol}` to the preamble,

That said, I don't find the formatting especially pleasant (particularly the weird offset of the enumeration labels and the corresponding text) and I would be inclined to instead set the whole set of sub-questions as a single `tabular` with the formatting:

```
\begin{tabular}{l@{\quad}rl@{hspace{2cm}}l@{\quad}rl}
a) & minimizar & $z = 3x_1 + x_2$ & c) & maximizar & $z = x_1 + 2x_2$\\
etc.
\end{tabular}
```

With an appropriate wrapping environment to display the `tabular`.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use `paracol` instead of `multicol` in order to better align the left and right columns, although this changed the enumeration order.

I increased `\arraystretch` so that every line has the same height.

I forced the arrays to have the same width by locating the widest entry and using `\makebox` to force one entry to be that wide (`\maxwidth`).  The vertical line on the right is just to check alignment (remove in final version).

It should be noted that one could just as easily used a tabular as an array, and `\centering $...$` instead of `\[...\]` (array uses `\textstyle`).  You could also use tabularx instead of paracol and lose the enumerate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter{enumi}
\newlength{\maxwidth}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\maxwidth}{$-2x_1 + 3x_2 \geq 9$}% widest engry
\begin{paracol}{2}
\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\item \[
\begin{array}{rl|} 
 \mbox{minimizar} & \makebox[\maxwidth][l]{$z = 3x_1 + x_2$} \\ 
 \mbox{sujeto a} & x_1 - x_2 \leq 1 \\
  & 3x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 12 \\
  & 2x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 3\\
  & -2x_1 + 3x_2 \geq 9\\
  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0
 \end{array}
\]
\switchcolumn
\item \[
\begin{array}{rl|} 
 \mbox{maximizar} & \makebox[\maxwidth][l]{$z = x_1 + 2x_2$} \\
  \mbox{sujeto a} & 2x_1 + x_2 \geq 12 \\
  & x_1 + x_2 \geq 5 \\
  & -x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 3 \\
  & 6x_1 - x_2 \geq 12 \\
  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 
 \end{array}
\]
\switchcolumn*
\item \[
\begin{array}{rl|} 
 \mbox{minimizar} & \makebox[\maxwidth][l]{$z = x_1 - 2x_2$} \\ 
 \mbox{sujeto a} & x_1 - 2x_2 \geq 4 \\
  & x_1 + x_2 \leq 8 \\
  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0
 \end{array}
\]
\switchcolumn
\item \[
\begin{array}{rl|} 
 \mbox{minimizar} & \makebox[\maxwidth][l]{$z = -x_1 - x_2$} \\ 
 \mbox{sujeto a} & x_1 - x_2 \geq 1 \\
  & x_1 - 2x_2 \geq 2 \\
  & x_1, x_2 \geq 0
 \end{array}
\]
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```